# Single entity to multiple repositories using spring data jpa

Tags: spring, hibernate, elasticsearch

I have some code that should read data from a RDBMS and insert it into Elasticsearch. I'd like to use same entity class for both repositories. Is it possible or generally, is it a best practice. I'm using Spring Data JPA, Hibernate and Spring BOOT.

My entity class called Contact with at least two `@OneToMany` annotation, you can find here:

```
@Entity
public class Contact {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="CONTACT_ID")
    private Long contactId;

    @Column(name="CONTACT_IDENTIFIER")
    private String contactIdentifier;

    //Some other properties

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="contact", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<ContactServiceEvent> listContactServiceEvent; 

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="contact", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<ContactVoiceServiceEvent> listContactVoiceServiceEvent; 

// setter getters
}
```

My repository interfaces are as follows

```
@Repository
public interface ContactRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Contact, Long>, ContactRepositoryCustom{
}

@Repository
public interface ContactDocRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Contact, Long> {

}
```

Please let me know how i should do that as i couldn't find any clear answer by googling.

Answer (score 0):

using hibernate, we can use same entity for different repositories, as i know you have to make different session factory for respective repository. In this case each session factory map to some repository, using datasource.
Then using different session factory, you can get data from different repositories by using same code.
I am not aware of how elasticsearch work. I think it will help you to proceed.

Comment: Thanks, may be i should be more clear in my first question. The main question is if im marking the same object as `@Entity` and `@Document` at the same time, will it cause any problems later on. Anyone had any experience?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Hibernate Search](http://hibernate.org/search/).

It was created for this purpose by the Hibernate team and is now able to synchronize with Elasticsearch as well.

Not only you'll get to use the same entities, but you won't need to bother with:

- serialization concerns and how to map your objects to JSON (you'll have to simply map properties to Elasticsearch fields).
- how to connect to the Elasticsearch server is taken care of, you only have to configure it.
- making sure to write all changes to both repositories. Writes are fully automatic.
- highly optimised for this purpose.